# Difficulty accessing data from twiitter using LinqToTwitter

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I am using the following code in C#

```
var users = (from user in twitterCtx1.User
             where user.Type == UserType.Lookup &&
                   user.UserID == list1
             select user)
             .ToList();
```

The list1 has all the IDs of the verified accounts of twitter and I am processing 75 records at a time. when I debug my code, I see that the list1 is populated with all the IDs but when the control passes in this portion of the code, it does not enter inside the it as the value being passed here is `NULL`

I am not able to understand as to why the value is `NULL`. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing `user.UserID` to the entire `list1` object. Did you mean to write `list1.Contains(user.userID)`?

Comment: What you are saying makes sense. However, if I change it to user.UserID == list1.Contains(user.UserID) when I get an error saying operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' or 'bool'. I guess I will have to reword it. I was under the assumption, just passing the list would work as it accepts multiple IDs and returns data.

Comment: However, I am using Linq, I believe the original code should work. There seems to be a bigger issue than this

Comment: @RichaSachdev No, you wouldn't compare it like that. You would replace the entire `user.userID == list1` portion with `list1.Contains(user.userID)`.

Comment: Thanks! however, gives me a new exception-"Query must contain one of either ScreenName or UserID parameters, but not both.\r\nParameter name: ScreenNameOrUserID"... I am passing just UserID. any idea why its picking up screen name too?

Comment: I think the LINQ to Twitter query is a bit different than I had originally thought (I've never used it). Try replacing the `user.userID == list1` line with something like `user.UserIDList = list1.Join(',')` (removing the `Contains` piece I told you about), such that you only have `user.Type` and `user.UserIDList` for your `where` clause.

Comment: Do you mean user.UserID= list.Join(',') ?

Comment: If `user.UserIDList` is a valid property then use that, otherwise try `user.userID`.  I don't have LINQ to Twitter to test which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear on what error you're seeing, but here are some tips that might help.

list1 needs to be a string that is a comma-separated list of user IDS. Here's some code to show how it works:

```
        var followers =
            (from user in twitterCtx.SocialGraph
             where user.Type == SocialGraphType.Followers &&
                   user.ScreenName == "JoeMayo"
             select user)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        var userIDs = string.Join(",", followers.IDs.Take(100).ToList());
        var users =
            (from user in twitterCtx.User
             where user.Type == UserType.Lookup &&
                   user.UserID == userIDs
             select user)
            .ToList();
```

First, the demo gets a list of user IDs. It's a user object with an IDs collection of type ulong. The next statement creates a comma-separated string of 100 of those IDs. Finally the lookup assigns that comma-separated string to the UserID property.

You should examine list1 and verify that it's a properly formatted comma-separated string of user IDs. The max size is 100.

Comment: I did this. This is how I did it first time and it gives me an error stating Uri String too long. If I replace user.UserID == list1 with                                            list1.Contains(user.UserID), then I get the error that it is getting both screen name and USerID. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but nothing seems to be working. I am doing 75 records at a time, so I am not exceeding any limits

Comment: The URI string problem occurs because I'm using a Get request, rather than a post. A work-around might be to reduce the number of user IDs at a time. I'm curious what the contents of list1 looks like.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I got that working. I wasn't realizing that the list was incarcerating each time and exceeded the 100 limit.

Comment: However, I have a question- I pulled the IDs of all verified accounts and they are close to 55K in number. Now, I am dividing that list into a string of comma separated IDS and then passing in lookup to get the details of each one of them. The loop goes on till I reach the end and withing in each loop I get data and add it to the data table. after sometime I reach rate limit exceeded error. Any hints what I can do? Do you need code to understand the process?

Comment: The Twitter API lists rate limits for each API in their docs, accessible from the bottom of the LINQ to Twitter page for that API. You can also do a Help/RateLimits query to get this info programmatically. Additionally, TwitterContext has RateLimit... properties that show the current rate limit on each query. Rate limits also vary by authorization type - e.g. ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer vs. SingleUserAuthorizer.

Comment: @JoeMayo This example is not working please look at line 80 https://github.com/nuvi/linqtotwitter/blob/4350418c8450b0bd1dbb3cbfa473219f0a159e96/LinqToTwitterDemo/UserDemos.cs 

What worked is ScreenNameList instead of ScreenName. Why so ?

Comment: @Freshblood You're looking at a copy of an old version of LINQ to Twitter. Check out line #93 here: https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/blob/master/New/Demos/Linq2TwitterDemos_Console/UserDemos.cs